Defining the type of an array that includes an Express controller with a validator or a spread array of validators
I'm rewriting the Local Library project from MDN in TypeScript and struggling to define the type of a controller that has validation checks.
const createAuthor: ValidatedHandler = [
  ...validate.authorData,
  async (req, res) => { /* controller */ },
];

const createGenre: ValidatedHandler = [
  validate.genre,
  async (req, res) => { /* another controller */ }
];

ValidatedHandler is a type I created and defined as follows:
import type { RequestHandler } from "express";
import type { ValidationChain } from "express-validator";

type ValidatedHandler = [...ValidationChain[], RequestHandler];

validate.authorData is an array of validators, and validate.genre is a single validator:
import { body } from "express-validator";

const authorData = [
  body("first-name")
    .trim()
    .notEmpty()
    .withMessage("First name must be specified."),
  body("family-name")
    .trim()
    .notEmpty()
    .withMessage("Family name must be specified."),
  // etc.
];

const genre = body("name")
  .trim()
  .notEmpty()
  .withMessage("Genre name must be specified.");

The spread operator in the type definition makes ValidationChain optional. If I remove ...validate.authorData or validate.genre, TypeScript has no problem with that. How can I fix that and make it so that at least one validator is required?
I've seen posts that suggest putting one type without the spread operator (i.e., [ValidationChain, ...ValidationChain[], RequestHandler]), but when I do that, VS Code has no problem with validate.genre but shows this error for ...validate.authorData:
Type 'ValidationChain | ((req: Request<ParamsDictionary, any, any, ParsedQs, Record<string, any>>, res: Response<any, Record<...>, number>) => Promise<...>)' is not assignable to type 'ValidationChain'.
  Type '(req: Request<ParamsDictionary, any, any, ParsedQs, Record<string, any>>, res: Response<any, Record<string, any>, number>) => Promise<...>' is missing the following properties from type 'ValidationChain': builder, not, withMessage, custom, and 117 more.

